# Javascript exercise "make all the values adjustable by the user"

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have this beginner Javascript coding challenge where I have to generate random characters and the user chooses the width, height and the "random" is the number of times that the random character appears in the loop as I understood.

**make all values adjustable by the user**

[image]

I know this solution is very simple, but I cant seem to reach it. This is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
        let width = prompt("Choose a Width value");
        let height = prompt ("Choose a height value");
        let random = prompt ("Choose a random value");

        let string = "";
        for(let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                string += "#";
            }
            string += "<br>";
        }

        const characters = '*';
            
            function generateRandomCode(){
                let result = ""
                let charactersLength = characters.length;
                for (let i = 0; i < random ; i++) {
                    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
                }
                return result
            }
        
        document.write(string);

    </script>
```

Does anyone know how to generate these random characters and make the user choose the number of times that it does?
Thank you <3

Comment: What is `generateRandomCode()` supposed to do? `characters` is only one character long, so there's no randomness... o.O

Comment: Generate the "grid" and replace `random` number of elements with `*`

Comment: Strings are immutable. It might be easier with a 2d array. Or even a 1d array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable. It might be easier with a 2d array.

```js
document.getElementById("calc").onclick = () => {
  const width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  const height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  const random = document.getElementById("random").value;

  // Create the 2d array, filled with '#'
  var arr = Array.from({length: height}, () => Array.from({length: width}, () => '#'));

  // Replace in array at random indexes
  let replaced = 0;
  while (replaced < random) {
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
    const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
    if (arr[x][y] !== '*') {
      arr[x][y] = '*';
      replaced += 1;
    }
  }

  // Convert to string
  let result = arr.join('<br/>').replaceAll(',','');
  
  // Display result
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `<pre>${result}</pre>`;
};
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="width">Width:</label>
  <input type="number" id="width" value="5" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="height">Height:</label>
  <input type="number" id="height" value="5" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="random">Random:</label>
  <input type="number" id="random" value="5" />
</div>
<div>
  <button id="calc">Go</button>
</div>
<div id="result">
```